# why postgres process doesn't run before execute RUN/CMD/ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

My first try, I got the error with this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:9.6-alpine
RUN psql

############# this is error message
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN psql                                                                                                                                                0.6s 
------
 > [2/2] RUN psql:
#6 0.349 psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
#6 0.349        Is the server running locally and accepting
#6 0.349        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

so I though this error's cause is no postgres process. and I tested something `CMD psql`, `ENTRYPOINT psql` then when i run this image after build, all container got same error. why do these problems happen?

Comment: There can be only one `ENTRYPOINT`, and it's either postgres server, or something else. What do you expect to achieve?

Comment: Running `psql` during the *build* stage seems really broken. Nothing will be running then you could connect to. Why not just `docker run -it --rm containername psql` instead?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use psql directly using Docker image,
I have this solution :

```sh
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --update add postgresql-client

ENTRYPOINT ["psql"]
```

after that:

```sh
docker build -t test .
```

and

```sh
alias psql='docker run --rm -it test:latest'
```

and finally start using psql :

```sh
psql --help
```

Demo:
[image]

I hope that this can help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

See [postgresql dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/Dockerfile#L187):

**Dockerfile:**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/docker-entrypoint.sh#L288):**

```
exec gosu postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

And if you define multiple `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in `Dockerfile`, only the last one will be used. That means your `CMD psql, ENTRYPOINT psql` will override the default `psql server` start command, which makes you still don't have a psql server process.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker container only runs one process.

If you set the image's `CMD` to be `psql` this runs *instead of* the base image's normal `CMD`; you get a PostgreSQL client *instead of* the PostgreSQL server.

Setting `ENTRYPOINT ["psql"]` doesn't really make sense to me, since its effect would be to cause the actual `CMD` to have `psql` appended to it; commands like `psql bash` don't actually make sense.  This also replaces the extensive startup-time script in the base image.  (But, see [@rassakra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67210145/10008173) for a specific pattern that uses it.)

If you `RUN psql`, that actually runs in its own container during the build phase.  The Docker image doesn't persist running processes, so this is the same situation as `CMD`: you have a container running `psql` and nothing else, so there's no database server for it to connect to.

During the build sequence there are three additional problems.  If you have a database running in another container, the image build isn't connected to any network in particular, so it can't connect to the database.  If you were planning to run the database with some storage attached, that's not available yet at build time.  In fact, the standard Docker Hub database images are configured so that you can't create a database image  with embedded data (because the server data is in a declared `VOLUME` and changes to `VOLUME` directories are not persisted).

---

If you're just trying to run `psql`, you can just run it, even if the database is in a container.

```sh
docker run -d -p 5678:5432 postgres
psql -p 5678
```

Or, if installing standard client tools is somehow unacceptable, you can launch a second Docker container connecting to the first one.  Both containers need to be on the same Docker network.  The `psql` client container can use the standard `postgres` image but specify an alternate command to run after the image name.

```sh
docker network create some-network
docker run -d --net some-network --name db postgres
docker run --rm -it --net some-network --name client postgres \
  psql -h db
```